# MySQL Unknown column in 'on clause' :(

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My query looks like

```
SELECT а.*, m.username, m.picture, m.picture_active
FROM questions_answer AS а 
INNER JOIN members AS m ON а.poster_id=m.member_id
INNER JOIN questions AS q ON q.question_id=a.question_id
ORDER BY a.postdate DESC
```

I'm getting error:

```
Unknown column 'a.question_id' in 'on clause'
```

I don't know what is wrong, please help me with this.

Table `questions` is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `questions` (
  `question_id` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `member_id` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `question` text NOT NULL,
  `postdate` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `active` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`question_id`),
  KEY `member_id` (`member_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

and `questions_answer` is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `questions_answer` (
  `answer_id` bigint(12) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `question_id` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `poster_id` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `body` text NOT NULL,
  `postdate` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`answer_id`),
  KEY `question_id` (`question_id`),
  KEY `poster_id` (`poster_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: Well... There is no column called `question_id` in your `questions_answer`-table.

Comment: Is there a field named question_id among your questions_answer table fields?

Comment: Does `questions_answer` table have a column named `question_id`? Doesn't appear so

Comment: See my answer, your alias is not character `a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table **`questions_answer`** may not have the column **`question_id`**

Comment: Well this query worked fine for me with the table structure. `SELECT a.*
FROM questions_answer AS a 
INNER JOIN questions AS q ON q.question_id=a.question_id
ORDER BY a.postdate DESC` , I just excluded the members table.

Comment: I found error. Thank's!
`$result = $DB->query("SELECT a.*,  q.question, m.username, m.picture, m.picture_active FROM questions_answer AS a
  INNER JOIN members AS m ON a.poster_id=m.member_id INNER JOIN questions AS q ON q.question_id=a.question_id ORDER BY a.postdate DESC") or die (mysql_error());`

Answer (score 0):

It would seem you don't have a column a.question_id

Check your structure for that table.

Answer (score 0):

There is not any column called `question_id` in the `questions_answer` table.

Answer (score 0):

Funny thing, if I use this code, it works:

```
SELECT qa.*
FROM questions_answer qa
INNER JOIN questions q ON qa.question_id = q.question_id
ORDER BY qa.postdate DESC
```

[SQL-fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce206/28/0)

So, to apply this to your query:

```
SELECT qa.*, m.username, m.picture, m.picture_active
FROM questions_answer qa
INNER JOIN questions q ON qa.question_id = q.question_id
INNER JOIN members m ON qa.poster_id = m.member_id
ORDER BY qa.postdate DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `questions_answer` table alias `a` has some issues. It most probably isn't the letter `a`.

```
FROM questions_answer AS а
```

I was playing around with it and found an error once that noted `Unknown table 'Ð°a':`  As you can see, it might be a special character. A short search on net came up with letter [Eth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eth)

I replaced the `alias` with character `a` and the query works fine.

```
SELECT a.*, m.username, m.picture, m.picture_active
FROM questions_answer AS a
INNER JOIN members AS m ON a.poster_id=m.member_id
INNER JOIN questions AS q ON q.question_id=a.question_id
ORDER BY a.postdate DESC
```

[See example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1c24/9)  Just copy paste your query there and try to run, it will complain because of `alias` character issue. You can even copy the alias from you line and replace all `a`s with it, it will work as well.